# Gauge invariance of 3-dimensional LQG action

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, loop-quantum-gravity

I'm going through C. Rovelli's [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107069629). On pages 91-93 he defines:

$$
U_e = {\cal{P}} \left\{ \exp \int_e \omega\right\} \in SU(2), \tag{4.30}
$$
$$
L_s^i = \int_s e^i \in {\mathbb{R}}^3. \tag{4.31}
$$

Where $\omega$ is a connection on the manifold, $e^i$ is a triad, $s$ is a segment of tetrahedron of triangulation $\Delta$ and $e$ is an edge in dual two-complex $\Delta^*$. He further writes:

> Therefore in the discrete theory the continuous local $SO(3)$ invariance is just reduced to rotations at the vertices. Not so for the algebra variables $L^i$ defined in $(4.31)$. To correct this, assume that this definition is taken in a gauge where the connection is constant along the segment itself (at the possible price of being distributional at the boundaries of the segment), as well as along the first half of each edge (edges are oriented). In this way, also the $L_s^i$ variables are invariant under all gauge transformations except those at the vertices; and they transform covariantly, in fact, in the adjoint representation, under rotation $R_v$ at the vertex $v$.

and defines the action on p. 93:
$$
U_f = U_{e_1} \dots U_{e_n} \tag{4.35},
$$
$$
S = \frac{1}{8 \pi G} \sum_f Tr\left( L_f U_f \right) \tag{4.36}
$$
where $f$ is a face around the segment $s$ and:
$$
L_f = L_{s_f}^i \tau_i
$$
for $\tau_i \in {\mathfrak{su}}(2)$ and $s_f$ being an unique segment crossing the face $f$.

---

According to the quote above and my common sense, $U_f$ (note the $f$ in subscript) are gauge-invariant by definition just as in the Lattice QCD. The $L^i$ are not invariant and transform under $SO(3)$. Combining these two together the action doesn't seem to be gauge-invariant. Am I mistaken?

Additionally I'm struggling to understand how gauge transformations at vertices (points in dual two-complex, one per each tetrahedra) must translate into the transformations of $L^i$.

---

To make things concrete, here is a complex (and its dual) that I tried to use as a semi-trivial example (sorry for terrible hand drawing):

[image: complex]

The faces are not displayed/numbered, but each is bound by two different edges. There are only 6 faces in this example. The complex consists of two tetrahedra with their faces glued to one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was mistaken.

$Tr(U_f)$ is gauge invariant, but $U_f$ itself transforms as:

$$
U_f \rightarrow W\left(R_{v_1} \right) U_f W^\dagger\left(R_{v_1}\right),
$$

where $W$ is a fundamental SU(2) representation of $SO(3)$ rotation $R_{v_1}$ at the first vertex of the $U_f$.

Thus after we assign a starting vertex for each face - we get:
$$
Tr(L^i_f \tau_i U_f) \rightarrow Tr\left( L^{'i}_f \tau_i W_{v_1} U_f W^\dagger_{v_1} \right) = Tr\left( L^{'i}_f \left( W^\dagger_{v_1} \tau_i W_{v_1} \right) U_f\right).
$$
Thus $t_i$ transforms as a vector and if $L^i_f$ has the same transformation - their contraction will be invariant. The content of blockquote above is exactly about fixing the transformation properties of $L^i_{f}$ by keeping connection constant on a segment and halves of the edges coming out of a vertex assigned to that segment.